# When i kill app broadcast receiver does not run in forground time will restart

Tags: android

Broadcast receiver can use to coundowntimer to set 10 minute time but 
when i kill application then timer well be restart please help..! 
how to solve ?

10 minute timer restart when close app , i reqired to when app will kied then timer will exicute in for graound.

**broadcastreceiver.class**

```
public class BroadcastService extends Service {
        static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS=600000;
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
        boolean mTimerRunning;
        long leftininmile=START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;

        private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";

        public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "mypackage.name";
        Intent bi = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            Log.i(TAG, "Starting timer...");

            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(leftininmile, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    leftininmile=millisUntilFinished;
                    int minutes=(int)(leftininmile/1000)/60;
                    int seconds=(int)(leftininmile/1000)%60;
                    String timeleftformat=String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d",minutes,seconds);
                    bi.putExtra("countdown", timeleftformat);
                    sendBroadcast(bi);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
                }
            }.start();
            mTimerRunning=true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelled");
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**fragment class**

```
  getActivity().startService(new Intent(getContext(), BroadcastService.class));

 private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateGUI(intent); // or whatever method used to update your GUI fields

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(BroadcastService.COUNTDOWN_BR));
        Log.i(TAG, "Registered broacast receiver");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(br);
        Log.i(TAG, "Unregistered broacast receiver");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        try {
            getActivity().unregisterReceiver(br);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Receiver was probably already stopped in onPause()
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getContext(), BroadcastService.class));
        Log.i(TAG, "Stopped service");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void updateGUI(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            String millisUntilFinished = intent.getStringExtra("countdown");
            luckytxt.setText(""+millisUntilFinished);
        }
    }
```

How can i solve it ? 
what my mistake ?
please help me ?
thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use forground service ? I think that will solve your problem as soon as your app get kill you can show timer (mm:ss) in notification via foreground service.

Comment: Thank you for Response. i well set timer when i kill app and back to app then my time well travel